# Chart.js in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

I have an MVC application with CHart.js.
Iam able to load the CHart.js on the View load event.

I want the Chart.js to be loaded on a html button click event.
On button click the controller is invoked and based on the search condition data is filtered.
I want this filtered content to be displayed on the chart.js.

How do i invoke the javascript function to load the chart on button click after the controller process is done on button click.

Flow should be
1. Enter the filter conditions
2. click button
3. controller fetches the data from the database based on filters
4. then the javascript function in the view is invoked to load the chart.js

Let me know how it has to be done.

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with chart.js, chart.js is a Javascript plugin, MVC is an architectural pattern. Please change your title and tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying data returned from your Controller in JavaScript you have two options:

**The First**:
using the razor syntax inside your View to refer to the model returned by the controller. This means that your JavaScript would also be written inside your View.

```cs
@model 'yourViewModel'

<div>
 //your view html code
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("button").click(function() {
   var chartData= @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.'nameOfYourModel'));

   var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

   var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data: chartData,
     options: options
   });

</script>
```

**The Second**:
Retrieve the data from your controller trough AJAX, for this I would recommend using the jQuery library. As it makes the syntax easier to write and understand.

```js
var chartData;
$('.button').click(function() { //your button
  $.ajax({ // Invoke controller action to retrieve data
    url: "path to your controller and its action",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
       chartData = data;
    }
  });

  var ctx = $("myChart").getContext('2d');

  var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data: chartData,
     options: options
  });
}
```

With this approach you call the controller action that returns your chart data in JSON format.

Comment: I tried option 2. the issue is that after the java script is executed, then only the server side controller code is invoked. so the chart data will not be available

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. But I think you mean that your page gets refreshed after calling the controller? And that results in the lost of your chart? If that's the case you should only return status Ok from your controller with the data that's needed for your chart. example: `return Ok(yourModel);` Or `return Ok(data = yourCollection);`